# Mutally exclusive constraints on two methods with the same signature

Tags: c#

So these two methods have the same signature but different constraints

```
public static void Method<T>(ref T variable) where T : struct { }

public static void Method<T>(ref T variable) where T : class { }
```

But they cannot be defined in a single class because they have the same signatures. But in this particular case they're mutually exclusive. (Unless I'm wrong about that)

I understand you can put additional constraints besides `class` and `struct` but you can't specify both `struct` and `class` on the same method. So why would this fail to compile?

Comment: You said it yourself, *because they have the same signatures*.

Comment: Do you have a workaround, because I've thought of one if you need it.

Comment: [Constraints are not part of the signature.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx)

Comment: @AnthonyPegram thanks, that's something I wasn't aware of.

Comment: @johnnyGold no, I don't need a work around but it was just something we came across at work that I found interesting and thought to ask it here :)

Comment: @jonnyGold : I have this problem, and it would be amazing if you give me the workaround you are talking about.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [generic constraints are not considered part of the method signature](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx) (thanks [@Anthony](https://stackoverflow.com/users/414076/anthony-pegram) for the link).

As far as the compiler is concerned you have a *duplicate* method - same numbers and types of parameters.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi Something that may be good or bad... to big a debate, for SO though.

Answer (score 4):

They are semantically mutually exclusive, yes.  But the compiler sees them as having the same "name", hence the ambiguity.  "Name" here meaning "method signature".

Comment: @L.B "name" being a colloquialism for "method signature"  I should be more explicit and not use hand-waver shorthand :)

Answer (score 4):

Although the compiler could be smart enough to figure it out (which it appears not to be), you do not know what to do for `object` (as it can be `class` or `struct`).